# Running the function written in Ionic in Xcode Swift

Tags: swift, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic application. I compiled this in Xcode for iOS and it works. I also created a widget for this application. My wish is that if the application opens with the normal application icon, the main screen should appear. However, if it is opened with a widget, it will redirect to another page. How can I do that? I tried many ways but couldn't find a solution.

For this, I tried to create a service on the Typescript side and do the routing there, but I cannot run the codes in typescript here.

Ts:

```
import { registerPlugin } from '@capacitor/core';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

// Define the interface
export interface MyServicePlugin {
  routeProfile(): any;
  routePage(): any;
}

// Implement the class
export class MyService implements MyServicePlugin {
  constructor(
    private navCtrl: NavController
  ) { }
  routeProfile() {
    console.log("sssssssss")
     return this.navCtrl.navigateForward(['/login-control']);
  }

  routePage() {
    console.log("ddddddd")
    return this.navCtrl.navigateForward(['/login-control']);
  }
}

const myService = registerPlugin<MyServicePlugin>('MyService');

export default myService;`
```

Swift Code:

```
import Foundation
import Capacitor

@objc(MyService)
public class MyService: CAPPlugin {

@objc func routePage(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {

}

@objc func routeProfile(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
        if let viewController = self.bridge?.viewController {
        //viewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "/login-control", sender: nil)
            call.resolve([:])
        } else {
            call.reject("NavController is not available.")
        }
    }
}
```

`

My Result in device:

```
To Native ->  MyService routeProfile 134138947
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a problem. I think you forgot to call the function.

Call func in ts file:

```
await myService.routeProfile();
```

Additionally, you can send parameters.

In swift:

```
call.resolve(["xxx":"yyy"])
```

You can get this value in ts file.

```
let xVal = await myService.routeProfile();
```